Trying get Odata but unable to create entityContainer; getDefaultEntityContainer giving null pointer error
I am using Apache Olingo lib to get the Odata. I am able to get EDM and metadata, but I'm unable to get entityContainer. I tried with default method also but getting null as result.
Here is sample code.
InputStream content = execute(serviceUri , APPLICATION_XML, HTTP_METHOD_GET);
edm =  EntityProvider.readMetadata(content, false); 
System.out.println("Read default EntityContainer: " + edm.getDefaultEntityContainer().getName());

Getting following error at the last line

the return value of "org.apache.olingo.odata2.api.edm.Edm.getDefaultEntityContainer()" is null

